# Would it be on-topic on Politics to ask whether video footage exists of Ukrainian celebration of the "Victory Day over Nazism in World War II"?

Tags: discussion, support, scope

Would it be on-topic on Politics to ask whether video footage exists of Ukrainian celebration of the "Victory Day over Nazism in World War II"?

All I could find in 30 mins of searching was https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XBDQu7RTgI4 which doesn't show wreathe laying by soldiers doing choreographed marching, but only shows some civilians putting some flowers/wreathes down informally.

I have searched YouTube and Google and couldn't find any. I'm curious to see whether the wreath laying looks anything like how it was done in Russia and Belarus on May 9th 2022.

The military ceremony involving laying wreathes on May 9th 2022 was remarkably similar in Belarus as in Russia, if anything, the movements of the soldiers were even more gymnastic, and so I was curious what the Ukrainian version looked like, and then I became very puzzled by not being to find anything on the internet that answered my question.

I could not find any footage showing  *any* May 9th wreathe laying from *any* year using the YouTube search engine, and then the Google one. I didn't come across so much as an still image of Ukrainian's in military uniform laying wreathes. I only could see that the flame they use in Ukraine in the same and comes out of the centre of a similar large five pointed star that is horizontal and about two meters in diameter as they have in Russia. I still don't even know whether the Ukrainian's do that gymnastic extreme goose step that looks so difficult or even the ordinary goose step that is used by the Russians and the Belarusians. Nor whether the Ukrainian ceremonial uniforms are or were similar to the Russian ones (the Belarusian one's are very similar to the Russian ones).

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wSxdfu3WPSc from 1:36:03 shows the Belarusian wreathe laying by Belarusian soldiers. At 1:18:44 in the same video you can see the Russian ceremony, with a very similar though less gymnastic placing of a 2m diameter wreathe by a pair of soldiers. The Russians have blue uniforms while the Belarusians have brown ones.

N.b. The proposed question is whether footage exists, not how can I find it and watch it.

Comment: I don't think it would be on topic but I am wondering what the goal behind knowing that is.

Comment: @JoeW The military ceremony involving laying wreathes on May 9th 2022 was remarkably similar in Belarus as in Russia, if anything, the movements of the soldiers were even more gymnastic, and so I was curious what the Ukrainian version looked like, and then I became very puzzled by not being to find anything on the internet that answered my question. If not on topic on Politics, why not? And where do you think it might be on-topic? Thanks in advance.

Comment: there's [Zelensky releases video on day of remembrance: 'We hear "never again" differently'](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CVlEkBHO_hc)

Answer (score 3):

*Welcome to Politics Stack Exchange!*

If your question is a one-liner equal only to it's title and if that were only

> Does video footage exists of Ukrainian celebration of the "Victory Day over Nazism in World War II"?

then no, that one-sentence question post would probably not be on-topic as it's not discernibly about politics as [@JoeW correctly asserts](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6257/16047).

But a Stack Exchange question is an entire post, not just a one-liner (most of the time) so I think that all is not lost.

You can certainly make an on-topic question out of this.

- Make sure it can be seen as a question about politics.
- Make sure it can have fact-based answers
- Make sure those answers are not trivially found; e.g. first paragraph of a Wikipedia article about the topic of your question
- Try to make sure the question will feel at least someone interesting to some fraction of the community who will help keep it open when [others don't think it's on-topic](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6257/16047).

So for example,

> Has Ukraine's celebrations of Victory Day traditionally been as much a showcase of political leaders and military strength as in some other countries?

That's exactly 150 characters.

In the body of the question you can suggest that evidence in photographs or videos would be helpful, and take your chances.

Or you can ask a [reference-request](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request) question and ask for help finding video materials *which may be useful assessing political aspects* of the celebrations.

Or I am sure you can think of other angles that keep your query at least arguably on-topic.

---

btw there's [Zelensky releases video on day of remembrance: 'We hear "never again" differently'](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CVlEkBHO_hc) but if "celebration" applies at all it's a stretch.

Comment: What you are suggesting as a question appears to be different then what they are looking to ask. Yes there are a lot of questions that are valid around the subject but that isn't what they are appearing to want to ask.

Comment: @JoeW it's called compromise, maybe we can't ask exactly what we want, but if we can come at it from a different angle and keep it on-topic and interesting everybody can benefit to some degree. Learning how to compromise comes with experience asking questions.

Comment: This isn't about compromising or not, the question they are looking to ask and get answered is off topic and there isn't anything changing that. You can suggest ways to make an on topic question but you also need to cover what they are actually asking about something being on topic.

Comment: @JoeW *my answer certainly is about compromise*; as a question that isn't exactly what we want to ask *may still lead to answers we find helpful!* Once you get some more experience asking questions you'll better understand the importance of compromise, unless of course you find being uncompromising more suitable.

Comment: You still should answer the question that was asked which if what they want to know is on topic or not.

Comment: While I do agree that it is off topic the length of the question is not why it would be off topic. Asking if a video exists or not is not something that would ever be on topic here.

Comment: @JoeW I've added a preamble, agreed with and linked to your answer and upvoted your answer

Answer (score 0):

From what I gather from your question and comments this would not be on topic and I do not think it would be on topic on any of the sites. It appears you are looking to find a video so that you can watch and and observe the event which is not what the site is for. That being said I do think you could ask about it in the chat and someone might be able to help you.